# I have a Skywin oud, 11 strings. Do the pegs need to be in a certain order, like in length?

Tags: maintenance, string-instruments, oud

So I'm not sure if my oud came strung correctly,they look a bit worn but it came with 6 pairs of replacement strings and one 11th string.

What if while restringing, I took all the pegs out without noting their original place, could I put the pegs back on the oud in any order?

Comment: It would make sense that they went back from whence they came. It sounds like it's been around a fair few years, so the fit for each will have been established.

Comment: That's a bad idea for *any* string instrument.  First, you don't want to completely detension  the instrument, so replace strings one at a time.  Next, as Tim says,  pegs are fitted (and "settle in" with use), so swapping them around can only lead to trouble.

Answer (score 2):

You say that your oud pegs are of different length.

The length of the peg is determined by the thickness of the string and the distance between the nut and the bridge of the oud. Thicker strings require longer pegs to provide enough space for winding and adjusting the tension, while thinner strings can use shorter pegs.

It is important to use the correct length peg for each string to ensure that the string is properly secured and can be tuned accurately. Using a peg that is too short or too long can cause the string to slip or not hold tension properly, resulting in an out-of-tune instrument.

Since the bridge is fixed, you can remove all the strings for a short period of time, but restring and retension as soon as you can.